# Give commands for an external Program in matlab

Tags: windows, matlab

Here is an short example what i want to do:

```
system('C:\.....\example.exe');
```

and now i want to give example.exe (Terminal Program without graphic user interface) the commands:

calculate random

export random.txt

quit

How does this work? If i do this in the command window it is easy and works so the system call is right. But i did not get how i give commands in the script.
Sorry for the stupid question but i did not found some working solution.
Thank you very Much!

Comment: Thank you! Thats what i was looking for!!!

Comment: Glad it works for you. I'll mark as duplicate then